# Deflect/ reflect object "shot" at surface using nodes

Tags: animation, physics

I've been trying to create a procedural animation where a set number of objects "emitted" from a set point moves towards random points on another object's surface. Once it collides with this object, it should be "absorbed", disappear, and then be "re-emitted" following the laws of reflection, meaning the "reflected" object should lie in the same plane as the original and follow the principle of the incident angle being equal to the reflected one. The objects should also be rotated accordingly so that the "front" is always pointing in the direction it is moving

[image: concept thrash]

Can such a thing be achieved using nodes or any other system?

Comment: Does it have to be nodes or can it be by any means? First though is you could just do a rigid body simulation and get all the physics and bouncing essentially for free.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Doesn't have to be nodes, I don't want my object to bounce but to dis- and reappear though

Comment: To be honest, it's not entirely clear to me from your sketch how you mean this. What exactly do you mean by "random point"? Where is this point, at which is reflected? Is the animation linear? Is it always a sphere that is to be reflected?

Comment: maybe you should tell us what the "end goal" is. Will you have lots of objects? or just one? should they be rotated too when reflected? And why do you want to make this with geometry nodes if you get if for free with rigid bodies?

Answer (score 2):

i have no idea whether this is the effect your are searching for....

but...here is my try:

Create two planes, the lower one with rigid body passive, and a "fake" plane with "nothing".
Uncheck gravity and you get:

[image]

Comment: I edited my question to try and explain my goal better, does this still apply when the object needs to be rotated?

Comment: @Toasdn You could use this method, bake the physics simulation to keyframes and then just manually adjust the rotation curves to be what you want. But this will get the location animation for you.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Thank you, will try it out. Would be nice to do this completely procedurally though.

Comment: You could consider looking into [animation nodes](https://animation-nodes.com/). I think it's only in the experimental feature set of Blender but that's where one would find what you're looking for, if it did exist.